# Incrementing date doesnt work as expected in javascript

Tags: javascript

Incrementing the date in javascript does not work as expected.

The functionality worked well before but I do not know why it is not working now.

Actual Result:
Tue Apr 30
Wed May 01
Sat Jun 01
Wed Jul 03
Sat Aug 03
Wed Sep 04
Sun Oct 06

Expected:
Tue Apr 30
Wed May 01
Thu May 02
Fri May 03
Sat May 04
Sun May 05
Mon May 06

```js
var dt = new Date();
var nextDay = new Date(dt);
nextDay.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);

document.getElementById("datetime1").innerHTML = ("0" + nextDay).substring(1, 12);
nextDay.setDate(dt.getDate() + 2);
document.getElementById("datetime2").innerHTML = ("0" + nextDay).substring(1, 12);
nextDay.setDate(dt.getDate() + 3);
document.getElementById("datetime3").innerHTML = ("0" + nextDay).substring(1, 12);
nextDay.setDate(dt.getDate() + 4);
document.getElementById("datetime4").innerHTML = ("0" + nextDay).substring(1, 12);
nextDay.setDate(dt.getDate() + 5);
document.getElementById("datetime5").innerHTML = ("0" + nextDay).substring(1, 12);
nextDay.setDate(dt.getDate() + 6);
document.getElementById("datetime6").innerHTML = ("0" + nextDay).substring(1, 12);
nextDay.setDate(dt.getDate() + 7);
document.getElementById("datetime7").innerHTML = ("0" + nextDay).substring(1, 12);
nextDay.setDate(dt.getDate() + 8);
```

```css
pre {
    display: block;
    unicode-bidi: embed;
    font-family: monospace;
    white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<pre id="datetime1"></pre>
<pre id="datetime2"></pre>
<pre id="datetime3"></pre>
<pre id="datetime4"></pre>
<pre id="datetime5"></pre>
<pre id="datetime6"></pre>
<pre id="datetime7"></pre>
```

Comment: You should use for-loop in this case. A small typo could break your code.

Comment: I made you a snippet so you have a [mcve]

Comment: Side note: `var nextDay = new Date(dt);` is not a reliable way to clone a date. It works/worked on some JavaScript engines and **not others**. To reliably clone a date, use the milliseconds-since-The-Epoch value from `getTime` (or a unary `+`): `var nextDay = new Date(dt.getTime());` or `var nextDay = new Date(+dt);`

Comment: maybe using moment.js can be usefull to format date if your source dates can have different format

Comment: @AlainIb For this simple issue, moment is a silly overhead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem is that you update `nextDay` based on `dt`:

```
nextDay.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
```

which potentially changes its month, and then repeatedly do it again:

```
nextDay.setDate(dt.getDate() + 2);
```

So:

- `nextDay.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);`: Setting day 30 on April 29th makes it April 30th
- `nextDay.setDate(dt.getDate() + 2);`: Setting day 31 on April 30th makes it May 1st (there are only 30 days in April)
- `nextDay.setDate(dt.getDate() + 3);`: Setting day 32 on May 1st makes it June 1st (May only has 31 days)
- `nextDay.setDate(dt.getDate() + 4);`: Setting day 33 on June 1st makes it July 3rd (June only has 30 days)

...and so on. Mixing the `dt.getDate()` with `nextDay.setDate` is what's tripping you up, because `dt` stays in April but `nextDay` moves to the next month.

Instead, just update the same date instance, moving forward by 1, and use a loop rather than repeating yourself:

```js
var dt = new Date();
var nextDay = new Date(+dt);

for (var n = 1; n <= 7; ++n) {
    nextDay.setDate(nextDay.getDate() + 1);
    document.getElementById("datetime" + n).innerHTML = ("0" + nextDay).substring(1, 12);
}
```

```css
pre {
    display: block;
    unicode-bidi: embed;
    font-family: monospace;
    white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<pre id="datetime1"></pre>
<pre id="datetime2"></pre>
<pre id="datetime3"></pre>
<pre id="datetime4"></pre>
<pre id="datetime5"></pre>
<pre id="datetime6"></pre>
<pre id="datetime7"></pre>
```

---

Side note:

```
var nextDay = new Date(dt);
```

is not a reliable way to clone a date. It works/worked on some JavaScript engines and *not others. To reliably clone a date, use the milliseconds-since-The-Epoch value from `getTime` (or a unary `+`):

```
var nextDay = new Date(dt.getTime());
// or
var nextDay = new Date(+dt);
```

I've done that above.

---

Side note 2:

`("0" + nextDay).substring(1, 12);` is an odd way to convert a date to a string. I'd probably use `String(nextDay).substring(0, 11)` instead, or a date formatting library.

Comment: Also ("0" + nextDay).substring(1, 12) could be a toString or toLocaledate

Answer (score -1):

Instead of

```
nextDay.setDate(dt.getDate() + 3);
```

you can try

```
nextDay.setDate(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate()+3);
```

Comment: This won't work. It *would* work if you used [`setFullYear`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setFullYear) instead of [`setDate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate). (not my downvote) –